# Referencing Entity

Tags: views, 8

Is there no current way to get a referencing entity from a view? When clicking on relationship it only shows content referenced from the field, not from the referencing entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not ready yet:

[Implement Entity Reference Backreferences](https://www.drupal.org/node/2497649)

But you can start from the other side. Start in views with the referencing entity and use a contextual filter with the referenced entity nid and then make the relationsship to get the fields of both entities.